Как удалить стикер из чата высланный ботом в тг, aiogram 3.8.0, на python?
Недавно начал практиковаться в этой области, долго пытался найти информацию, зашёл в тупик.

удаляется так же как и обычное сообщение (await bot.delete_message(message_id, chat_id))

Спасибо за ответ, я так попробовал сделать, но у меня удаляется сообщение до стикера, а не сам стикер. Почему так происходит?

Вы когда отправляете стикер, у вас должна быть переменная message (она возвращается при отправке await bot.send_message/answer или еще что вы там отправляете) и в ней должна быть переменная message_id или просто id. Ее надо сохранить и затем удалить, скорее всего вы взяли id из предыдущего сообщения

Спасибо,  всё заработало.
